# Hide MasterViewController from DetailViewController in a SplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a SplitViewController set up with a DetailViewController and a MasterViewController. The DetailViewController contains a map and I want to place a button on the map that collapses and expands the MasterViewController. Exactly like this in Apple's App Store app:

[image]

Clicking on the button then gives:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can achieve a similar effect? Note I don't want to close the top tool bar, just the MasterViewController. Thanks!

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Pravin, my final solution in the IBAction is:

```
if (self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
    self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
} else {
    self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
     [self.splitViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
 }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hide master view

```
AppDelegate * appDelegateObj = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        UISplitViewController * splitView = appDelegateObj.splitViewObj;
        splitView.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
         {
             [spv.view layoutIfNeeded];
         }];

show master view


AppDelegate * appDelegateObj = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        UISplitViewController * splitView = appDelegateObj.splitViewObj;
        splitView.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
         {
             [spv.view layoutIfNeeded];
         }];
```

I hope it will useful for you!

Comment: Thanks Pravin! I used your code as a base, but simplified it a little. I've updated my answer with my code.

Comment: @samturner: thats great!